# Why firefox page scrolling is slow on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, firefox, browser

Why on the firefox default installation (on 14.04) the page scrolling is so slow?

With Chromium I haven't this problem.

My hw: 4GB RAM and a nvidia video card (9600 GT).

Thanks!

Comment: Could you edit your question and make it a bit less subjective? Slow is such a relative term.... A drive with Grandma might make that obvious......

Comment: Well, it seems fixed "Upgrade: firefox:amd64 35.0+build3-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 to 35.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to install your video cards drivers.  By default ubuntu usually installs the open source version which sometimes don't work as well.

You can find out if this is the case by type "Additional Drivers" into the launcher -> search scopes.

It should look something like this. Make sure you pick the Nvidia Legacy I believe is the correct version for your Video Card.
[image]

You can also try and enable smooth scrolling in Firefox if it isn't activated.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, good tip. However with Chromium the problem don't exist, so I think this is a issue with firefox on Ubuntu (maybe with all linux distros, I dunno).

Comment: Look at my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks, excellent tip! But the last upgrade (today morning GMT-2) from canonical seems to fix the issue: "Upgrade: firefox:amd64 35.0+build3-0ubuntu0.14.04.2, 35.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1".