# Firefox page on ubuntu 15.10 scrolling slow, but the same page runs Ok with Chrome

Tags: firefox, 15.10, flash, scrolling

Everytime i open the page ''http://portal.pixelfederation.com/'' then click on Trainstation (that uses flash player) and waits the page load completely using Firefox Browser I notice the scrollbar bar lagging when i move it down and open anyway, but when I open the same page using the Chrome browser the scrolling runs preety well, i dont know about me but i think Chrome shows pretty more efficient with this page than Firefox, I don't know why.

I've already installed all the latest graphic card drivers for my laptop, the latest Adobe Flash player for Mozilla, Pepper flash player pluggin, PPAPI host and NPAPI plugin adapter, but the issue persists only with Firefox.

I'm using a ASUS S400CA laptop with Core i3 2365M, 4GB of ram DDR3, a 5400rpm Sata Hard disk, and Intel HD Graphics 3000 onboard.

I read this page before, i think it points the same problem or very similar :
[Why firefox page scrolling is slow on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/578366/why-firefox-page-scrolling-is-slow-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably either a bug in Firefox (maybe) or due to the fact that Firefox in Linux only gets Flash version 11 (probably).  Sadly, Adobe has stopped making new versions of Flash for Firefox on Linux (only security updates now), but continues to make new versions for Chromium (and Chrome).  Because the site uses Flash and the problem only affects that site, the site probably needs a newer version of Flash to work normally.

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue seems to be ok right by now on Firefox, i went to Ubuntu software center the searched for''Pepper flash'' on the search camp, then installed all the results that was not selected with the ''green V''. After this i searched for ''Adobe flash player firefox'' then noticed it was not installed (maybe because i updated Adobe flash firectly from Firefox), anyway i clicked on the result that appeared, it was the Adobe flash plugin installer for mozilla, then scrolling a bit down the page I selected all the Optional extensions then i clicked Apply and installed all of it, After closing Firefox and re-open it on Trainstation portal page i noticed the scrollbar moving smoothly so far.

Boring and serious if Adobe definetely stops upgrading flash versions for firefox, hope this for good not happen through we Linux users.

I thank you for the answer.

Comment: Source of info on Adobe not releasing new versions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/172783/adobe-will-stop-releasing-new-versions-of-flash-what-will-happen-to-flash-supp

Comment: Thankfully everything in moving to HTML5 and JavaScript.